# Why does a bash command return "... is a directory"?

Tags: bash, cordova

When I follow the steps for starting a new Cordova PhoneGap project for Eclipse (following these directions: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android ), I drag Android's /bin directory to the Terminal window first (which contains the create script), then type in:

```
./create /Users/Steve/Documents/PhoneGap_apps/PhoneGap_apps/appName2 com.companyname.appName2 appName2
```

to create the project.

But what I get in return is:

```
-bash: /Users/Steve/Downloads/phonegap-phonegap-8a3aa47/lib/android/bin: is a directory
```

The appName2 directory is not created.

Why do I get that "is a directory" notice, and how do I resolve it to create the directory?

Comment: If you drag a directory to the Terminal and press return, then you will see this message because the directory cannot be interpreted as a command. To navigate to a directory, first type `cd ` (note the trailing space) then drag the target directory into the Terminal and press return to change directories. Did the error message appear at this stage, or not until after you typed the `create` command? And did you start a new line for it?

Comment: The message appears after I run the create command, not before. I did not start a new line, but dragged in the /bin directory, then copy/paste the address in, with a space between the two, and no space after. Then I hit Return. I tried the cd also, and "is a directory" did not appear, but neither did the directory get made.

Comment: If I do a cd, then drag the bin, then hit Return, then add the path, I get the message, An error occurred. Deleting project...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Fixed path.

I think you're missing a tilde (~) in your path.

Try this:

```
./create ~/Documents/PhoneGap_apps/PhoneGap_apps/appName2 com.companyname.appName2 appName2
```

Comment: Doubtful. `/Users/Steve` probably is the home directory. If so, then `~/Users/Steve` would expand to `/Users/Steve/Users/Steve`.

Comment: ~ means home directory, in this case /Users/Steve. With a prefixed tilde the full path would read /Users/Steve/Users/Steve/Documents/... and so on.

Comment: Edit: Oh just saw my mistake ^^

Comment: Try again Steve, fixed the path.

Comment: I copied your version and pasted it in. Still resulted in same notice. If the tilde means /Users/Steve, then why would it make any difference? Thanks!

Comment: I obtained the directory path after ./create by dragging the final PhoneGap_Apps directory to the Terminal, so it is correct.

Comment: Obviously no difference. I just tried this on my local machine and gave you my working example with your path's.  Does other bash scripts work?

Comment: Is the target folder empty?

Comment: As a matter of fact, the target folder (appName2) is not made by me at all. The script is supposed to create it. If I create it first then run the script, the message returned is: "Project already exists! Delete and recreate"

Answer (score 0):

I successfully created the folder based on Marcus' response by adding the "cd" first, then adding the entire script. Earlier, attempting his answer, I had first hit Return after dragging the /bin folder over, then adding the script. Doing all three components on a single line did the job.